# why is the array/object I pass to my foreach loop flagged as a bool?

Tags: php, foreach, boolean

the code works, but flags a warning:

**Warning**: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool given

this is the code
(a function that is given a regular expression and then counts how many values in the cvs match the expression):

```
function count_matches($pattern) {
                        
      global $fileDestination;
      $file_to_read = fopen($fileDestination, 'r');
      $c = 0;                        

      while(! feof($file_to_read)) {                      
                        
          foreach (fgetcsv($file_to_read) as $value) {
                
            if (preg_match($pattern, $value)) {

              $c ++;
              }
          }
      }

      return $c;
      fclose($file_to_read);
                    
}
```

like I said the code works, $c is being returned, but I need to get rid of the warning and I don't understand where it is coming from.

Comment: [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) returns `false` in case of errors

Comment: `why is the array/object I pass to my foreach loop flagged as a bool`...because it isn't an array or object, it's a bool. The PHP engine doesn't lie to you. `I don't understand where it is coming from` ...wel, since the error comes from `foreach (fgetcsv($file_to_read) as $value)`, and therefore what's being passed into the loop must come from `fgetcsv($file_to_read)`, then it's easy to see that it comes from the call to `fgetcsv`. And if you read the documentation, as Cid pointed out, it explains why it might return a bool. It's all entirely logical, if you just take time to follow it.